# how to find if a sum "N" is possible taking only k elements from a given array A

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Recently, I came across the following problem:

**k-Subset Sum**

You are given an array A[] of positive integers containing N elements. Now you need to form a new array containing K elements from the given array A[] and also its sum should be equal to S. Also the newly formed array of size K should be lexicographically minimal.

Constraints

size of the given array A[] (<=10^5).

integer K , size of newly formed array (<=10^5).

sum of newly formed array (<=10^5).

**My Approach**

It looks like a dp problem to me where at each index 'i' , I have to decide to either pick or leave behind the item, and then possibly backtrack to find the answer. I was only able to come up with the state
dp[i][j][k] : is it possible to reach ith index having collected j items which sum up to k.

I didn't go forward with approach since this will surely give TLE O(n^3) and n~~10^5 . Is there an approach possible which can solve this in O(nlog(n))?

Comment: What is the range of the numbers? What is the expected value of `K` ?

Comment: @amit edited the question to reflect constraints

Comment: Thanks. Are integers unique? (This is important since in your case, the sum is the same as the number of elements, if the integers are unique and positive, at worst case you get `1+2+...+m-1+m = 10^5`, and since this is sum of arithmetic progression, maximal value of `m` is `~2*sqrt(10^5)`, cutting your runtime by ~x300

Comment: @amit there is no such constraint for this question. But I see your point, what did you have in mind if they are unique?

Comment: Doing your approach, but being very sensitive to any early termination possible when it's clear it won't yield a good result. I am not sure in the general there is a better solution. For unbounded subset sun (any elements you want) the complexity is O(nW) where W is the requires sun. I. Your case, n=W.

Comment: Refer to https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/60596